# Problem in Creating history record using Django Simple History

Tags: django, python-3.6, django-simple-history

Why Django-Simple history records get created on calling save method if I call update then it doesn't create history record ?

Django : 1.11.15
Django-simple-history : 1.9.0
Python : 3.6

Comment: If you `.update(..)` this circumvents the `.save(..)` method, it simply creates an UPDATE query to update the records in *bulk*, so you can not use this that way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So if i want to create history for a row on update then first i have to save that row,Is it? Is there any way to create history for a row on update ?

Comment: no, since `.update(..)` creates a query like `UPDATE table SET field = value WHERE some_condition`. This is why the `.update(..)` has a performance boost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As is written in the [documentation](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.1/reference.html#bulk-creating-and-queryset-updating) this is a known issue:

> Django Simple History functions by saving history using a `post_save`
> signal every time that an object with history is saved. However, for
> **certain bulk operations, such as `bulk_create` and queryset `update`s, signals are not sent, and the history is not saved
> automatically**. However, Django Simple History provides utility
> functions to work around this.

So basically the app makes use of the fact that you `.save()` the model, and this is *circumvented* by some ORM calls (because then you can not perform the actions in "bulk" at the database level anymore).

Instead of using

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010).update(comments_on=False)
```

you thus need to perform:

```
for e in Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010):
    e.comments_on = False
    e.save()
```

For a `bulk_create` there is a variant: [**`bulk_create_with_history`**](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#bulk-creating-and-queryset-updating), since then it simply makes two bulk creates: one for the objects, and one for the "histories".